# Rails: store translations in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, internationalization, backend

I was searching for a plugin/gem solution to extend the native rails i18n for storing my translations into my database. Maybe I used the wrong search terms, but all I found was the information, that changing the backend IS actually possible and this [blog entry](http://www.viget.com/extend/rails-internationalization-and-tu) which descripes how to write my own backend.

It's hard to imagine, that all those rails apps out there having their translations stored in yml-files or every developer wrote own backends!

Do you know working solutions for this? Storing multiline texts in yml really gets me down! ;)

Thanks and greets,

Joe

Answer (score 21, accepted):

i18n has built-in support for using the database as a translation backend.

Create a table using this code in a migration:

```
   create_table :translations do |t|
     t.string :locale
     t.string :key
     t.text   :value
     t.text   :interpolations
     t.boolean :is_proc, :default => false
   end
```

Then add an initializer in config/initializers/i18n.rb with contents:

```
   I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new
```

And last... put translations in the table.  Something like:

```
locale key      value
en     Cool     Cool
es     Cool     Frio
en     nav.Home home
es     nav.Home casa
...
```

As of i18n 0.5.0 I believe they moved this code out into it's own gem... I forget what that gem is called.

Comment: The Rails Guides have some stuff on this topic (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-backends). Thanks for filling in the gaps @Jason!

Answer (score 9):

I finally found what I was looking for with the help of Sven Fuchs:

> http://github.com/dylanz/i18n_backend_database/tree/master

This quite awesome plugin by Dylan Stamat does exactly what the name indicates and additionally handles the caching!

Sven also mentioned, that the current branch of i18n/active_record provides an ActiveRecord backend as well:

> http://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/active_record/lib/i18n/backend/active_record.rb

Some discussion about this topic is going on in the goolge i18n user group:

> http://groups.google.com/group/rails-i18n/browse_thread/thread/6b7ba3c401890a7e

Issue solved, thanks to Mr *I18n* Sven Fuchs! ;)

Comment: Nice! Good to hear you have a nice solution. Thanks for sharing, too.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try http://github.com/joshmh/globalize2/tree/master

Comment: Hello Aram,
okay, globalize makes it easy to translate model related content, but what about all the static content like imprint, about, e-mail content etc?

Comment: I imagine you would have to write your own backend then. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: My current project has to handle with a lot of description texts - but because it'll get more dynamic in future we decided to use rails from the beginning. Now our yml-files have more than 1000 lines! Perhaps I'll create a model and store serialized key-value pairs in it. Not beautiful at all, but a compromise..

Answer (score 0):

We had a good experience with [fast_gettext](http://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext/)

it has a DB-backed backend that comes with a controller to do the translations over the web.
The caching is built-in, though we had to code pre-loading of all of the translations on boot (it is much faster then get them one-by-one with caching).

Comment: Could you share the preloading in fast_gettext wiki, so others can reuse it ?