# Rails 3.2, internalization of values habtm & i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Hi im working in Ruby on Rails app for the moment the only problem i have faced is with this same question asked here [Rails 3.1, internalization of values from a habtm relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101268/rails-3-1-internalization-of-values-from-a-habtm-relationship)

Ive tryed to apply the solution but i can not define the languages: (instead of categories) well

here is part of my lenguage file es-MX.yml just as example.

```
  languages:
        english: 'Inglés'
        spanish: 'Español'
        french: 'Francés'
        german: 'Alemán'
        portuguese: 'Portugués'
        italian: 'Italiano'
        japanese: 'Japonés'
        chinese: 'Chino'
        arabic: 'Árabe'
        russian: 'Ruso'
        espanol: 'Español'
```

This is the View :

```
<div id="idiomlen">

    <%= f.label        :languages %>

    <% for language in Language.find(:all) %>
      <div class="idiomlenbox"><%= check_box_tag "player[language_ids][]", language.id, @player.languages.include?(language) %>
      <%= language.name %></div>
    <% end %>

    <div id="idiomlenotro">
      <%= f.label      :other_languages %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :other_languages %>
    </div>

  </div>
```

And this is part of the model

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :clubs
  has_many   :links
  has_many   :references
  has_many   :achievements
  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :selections
```

Does anyone has an idea to fix this..

I dont get any error, i think actually i18n is using a "default" values cause spanish and english are kind of working, i just cant define the specific text i need for each language.

Thanks in advance, Kind regards.

EDIT : Also in seeds.rb i have this

```
roles = %w{
  admin
  elite
  player
}

languages = %w{
  english
  spanish
  french
  german
  portuguese
  italian
  japanese
  chinese
  arabic
  russian
}

idiomas = %w{
  ingles
  espanol
  frances
  aleman
  portugues
  italiano
  japones
  chino
  arabico
  ruso
}
```