# Rails 'label' value to be save to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, label

Is there a way or is it possible to save in the database the value of the label tag?

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :cust_name %><br />
 <div><label id="cust_name" name="delivery_receipt[cust_name]"></label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all is possible, but what exactly you want to do with labels? maybe you about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346939/rails-store-translations-in-database

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would have the label and the input field alongside each other:

```
<%= f.label :cust_name %>
<%= f.text_field :cust_name %>
```

This would display the label and an input field. The value entered by the user will be saved against `cust_name` in the DB.

**Value of `f.label`**

The value of f.label would simply be the symbol name (cust_name). This should be the name of one of your model attributes so generally you wouldn't want to save this to the DB.