# How can I load different model with different language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a tables with content in two languages. Then I have a column called 'language' to distinguish.Now I use I18n to do multi languages website.So, how can I get content in database with current language?

I think that if I can set the default_scope of model accoding to the language, or load different models the same name.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at [Rails: store translations in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346939/rails-store-translations-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL parameter to set the application locale for a request, for example:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale
 
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

Find the model by current locale:

`YourContent.where(name: some_name, language: I18n.locale)`

and use the `t` method in views with your strings files since you have the application locale set.

The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) have a few other examples.

Yes, you can use `default_scope { language: I18n.locale }` to omit the extra `where`, but be aware of the [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087336/why-is-using-the-rails-default-scope-often-recommend-against) of `default_scope`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch to different table conditionally for same model, you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.table_name` class method.

Example:

```
cTable4 ❯ rails c -e production
Running via Spring preloader in process 60375
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.4)
irb(main):001:0> Book.first
  Book Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books"  ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Book id: 1, name: "ELoquent Ruby", author: "Russ", year: "2011", created_at: "2016-01-07 08:40:47", updated_at: "2016-01-07 08:40:47">
irb(main):002:0> Book.table_name = 'titles'
=> "titles"
irb(main):003:0> Book.first
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "titles".* FROM "titles"  ORDER BY "titles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Book id: 1, title: "Practical OOD Ruby", author: "Sandi Metz">
irb(main):004:0>
```