# Rails: i18n translation of a string stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a table with columns that contain a string. For simplicity let's say the possible values are 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', stored in the DB in English.

For my different locales I wish to translate this string using i18n.

My guess was to add to my nl.yml

```
"Apple": "Appel"
"Pear": "Peer"
"Banana": "Banaan"
```

And then add to my view

```
<%= t(@fruit.name) %>
```

But this does not quite work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post what error you are getting ?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4263773/4758119

Comment: It seems, this is the correct way. I must have made a typo somewhere...